# Dynamic for loop function for filtering df based on provided parameters

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

If I wanted to create a new df that only had rows from the original df that fall into specified categories, what would be the most efficient way to do that?

```
df = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')

def makenewdf(cuts=['Ideal','Premium'], df=df):
[some kind of loop to dynamically filter df based on the values of cuts]
```

what would be the best way to make this function such that I could provide the categories I want to sequester?

ex: `makenewdf(cuts = ['Good'])` would return a df containing only rows where the cut was 'Good' and `makenewdf(cuts = ['Good','Ideal','Premium'])` would return a df with only rows containing one of the three values in cuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching for the `isin()` function, you can use something like this:

```py
def makenewdf(cuts, df):
    return df[df.cut.isin(cuts)]

# Example
print(makenewdf(['Good'], df))

# Example
print(makenewdf(['Good','Ideal','Premium'], df))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the dataframe like this:

```
filtered_df = df[df['cuts'].isin(['Ideal', 'Premium'])]
```